# Kendo UI .. translate datasource data before sending to Grid.

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have some data that looks like:

```
   {
      "Data":[
         [
            {"Key":"Commonality","Value":0},
            {"Key":"Item","Value":"ExampleItem"
         ]
        "Total":2,
        "AggregateResults":null,
        "Errors":null
       ]
   }
```

The format of the JSON cannot be changed.

I need to somehow translate the data to:

```
   {
      "Data":[
         [
            { Commonality:0}, Item:"ExampleItem"}
         ]
        "Total":2,
        "AggregateResults":null,
        "Errors":null
       ]
   }
```

Does Kendo UI have a callback I can use to process the data and pass it back to the datasource once it's been received?

Answer (score 1):

Literally moments after posting my question I realised that I was 99% there!

I was just missing the Total, AgggregateResults etc from my translate function

```
       function parseFunction(response) {
            var result = [];

            var data = response.Data;

            for (var irow = 0; irow < data.length; irow++) {
                var newRecord = {};

                for (var icol = 0; icol < data[irow].length; icol++) {
                    var record = data[irow][icol];

                    newRecord[record.Key] = record.Value;
                }
                result.push(newRecord);
            }
            response.Data = result;
            return response;
        }
```

And here is it being used in a data source :)

```
        function CreateDataSource() {
            var source = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: 'GetFixturesReport',
                    }
                },
                pageSize: itemsPerPage,
                type: 'aspnetmvc-ajax',
                serverPaging: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverSorting: true,

                schema: {
                    data: 'Data',
                    total: 'Total',
                    errors: 'Errors',
                    //model: { id: 'Fixture' },
                    parse: parseFunction,
                }
            });
            return source;
        }
```

I now have a way to supply C# Dynamic objects to a grid view so that I can have truly dynamic columns. It has taken me a lot of experimentation though!

Hope this helps someone else.

Kiran